# pandas "groupby" produced a level in headers that is unable to access or delete

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, data-science

```
df_india = pd.read_csv('fakepath\file.csv')

df_india.head()
```

[image]

After cleaning, the data frame looks like this

```
df_india.head(5)
```

[image]

Since i want to group by state

```
df_india = df_india.groupby(by=['State']).sum()
df_india.head(5)
```

[image]

> Here comes the unnecessary level, but i am unable to access or remove
> the 'State' level. I want both the columns on the same level as
> headers for the dataFrame

I tried resetting index, then the headers appear like a single level headers.

```
df_india.reset_index().head(2)
```

[image]

But still unable to access 'State' column

```
df_india['State']
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `as_index` parameter in `groupby()` method and set that equal to `False`:-

```
df_india = df_india.groupby(by=['State'],as_index=False).sum()
```

now write:-

```
df_india['State']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign dataframe back when you use `reset_index()`

```
df = df_india.reset_index()
```

Or you can use `inplace=True` while calling `reset_index()`

```
df_india.reset_index(inplace=True)
```